# Find the character at the `k`th location in the infinite string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem:

Given two strings, `s` and `t`, we can form a string `x` of infinite length, as:

```
a. Append s to x 1 time;
b. Append t to x 2 times;
c. Append s to x 3 times;
d. Append t to x 4 times;
and so on...
```

Given `k`, find the `k`th character (1 indexed) in the resultant infinite string `x`.

For e.g., if s = `a`, t = `bc` and k = 4, then output: `b` (x=`abcbc`). `s` and `t` can contain anywhere from 1 to 100 characters, while 1<=`k`<=10^16.

The brute force way of actually constructing string `x` is trivial but too slow.  How do I optimize it further?

In C++, the brute force solution would look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int repeat=1, k=4;
    string s="a", t="bc", x;
    bool appendS=true;
    
    while(x.size()<k) {
        for(int i=1; i<=repeat; i++)
            if(appendS) x+=s;
            else x+=t;
        appendS=!appendS;
        repeat++;
    }
    
    cout<<x[k-1];
    
    return 0;
}
```

But how do I optimize it, given huge `k`?

Comment: It is really trivial, actually.....

Comment: @Brethlosze, _it_ as in?  Which one?

Comment: Can somebody move this to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)? There we can add some formulas for placing a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string looks like

```
sttsssttttsssssttttttssssssstttttttt...
```

Group the string into substrings like

```
(stts)(ssttttss)(sssttttttsss)(ssssttttttttssss)(sssss...
```

Let

```
len(s) = a
len(t) = b
len(s+t) = c
```

Group 1: `stts` -> length = `2*c`.
Group 2: `ssttttss` -> length = `4*c`.
Group 3: `sssttttttsss` -> length = `6*c`.

Continuing the pattern, it is easy to see that the length of `ith` group will be `2*i*c`.
Let the `kth` character be in group `n`.
Total length of first `n` groups =

```
2*c + 4*c + 6*c .... + 2*n*c = (2*c)*(1+2+3...+n) = c*n*(n+1)
```

Since total length of `n` groups has to be greater than or equal to `k`,

```
c*n*(n+1) >= k
n*(n+1) >= k/c
```

Finding the largest value of n that satisfies this inequality is a trivial task. Now, the `nth` group looks something like

```
ss...(n times) + tttt...(2*n times) + ss...(n times)
```

Now, you just need to find the position of `k mod n` in this block, which is a simple task.

Comment: Great answer! Could you elaborate why the `n`th group looks so?  Also, how to find the position of `k mod n` in this block

Comment: @Someone look at the initial grouping, we create symmetrical groups with pattern ```(s*n) + (t*2*n) + (s*n)```. As for finding ```k mod n```, there are three regions in the group: the starting ```s``` block, the ```t``` block, and the last ```s``` block. Find which block does ```k mod n``` belong to. Finally, find ```(k mod n) mod x```, where ```x = len(s) or len(t)``` according to the block

Comment: "Find which block does `k mod n` belong to." - how?  IMO that is the crux of the problem that I am having difficulty in.

Comment: @Someone there are literally 3 ranges: ```[0,n*a], [n*a, (n*c + n*b)], [(n*c + n*b), 2*n*c]```. It is easy to deduce which range would ```k mod n``` lie in

Answer (score 2):

The search position is located at the nth append, where n is calculated for the last integer where this sum inequality holds, where l1 and l2 are the two strings lengths:

[image]

Hence, the search position is at the nth append, at the mod(n+1,2)+1 string, in the Delta k character of that string.

Explanation:

The sum is the addition of all lengths. Since you know all the substrings, you know the whole sum. And since both are integer algebraic expression, you have to do a little linear search over that, to find that integer n, as in any simple integer equation.

Having the nth append number, and the sum, the position is trivially obtained as Delta k.

Moreover, note that Delta k is a closed expression. You do not need any loop to calculate it, just to evaluate, since the sums of the i terms are the sum of the first floor(n/2) even and the first floor(n/2)+1 odd integers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you derived the formula?